# How to clear readonly

Tags: jquery, readonly-attribute

I need to add a prefix to a form input based on the country and to prevent that prefix from being edited. I have it working correctly as far as setting it is concerned but when I switch countries the block (readonly) isn't clearing. The input clears but the first three columns are still readonly. I've searched threads here and they mostly all say to use the attr("readonly", false) statement but that is not working for some reason. Would someone please point out the problem?

```
<div>
 <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
 <div>
   <select name="country" id="inputCountry" onchange="SetPhonePrefix();">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="84">Greece</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
function SetPhonePrefix() {
  var ctrl = document.getElementById("inputCountry");
  var country = ctrl.options[ctrl.selectedIndex].text;
  var doLock = false;

  if (country == 'Greece') {
    document.getElementById('inputFax').value = '+30';
    doLock = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('inputFax').value = '';  
    $("#inputFax").attr("readonly", false);    
  } 

  if (doLock) {
     var readOnlyLength = $('#inputFax').val().length;
     $('#inputFax').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
       if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
           && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
           || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
           return false;
       }
     });  
  } 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `readonly`. This is for when you don't want the user to enter **anything** in the field. In your case, you only want to limit the **start** of the input.

By using classes and data attributes, you can re-use code on multiple pages without repeating your JavaScript code.

You need two functions - one for when the `select` is changed, and one for when the `input` is changed. If you use `$(document).on()` it will monitor both static and dynamic inputs. Also, use `'input'` to monitor all changes to an input, including copy and paste.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.prefix-select', function(){
  var prefix = $(this).find(':selected').data('prefix');
  $(this).closest('form').find('.prefix-input').data('prefix', prefix).val(prefix);
});
$(document).on('input', '.prefix-input', function(){
  var prefix = $(this).data('prefix');
  if($(this).val().lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0){
    $(this).val(prefix);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="prefix-select">
    <option data-prefix="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="84" data-prefix="+30">Greece</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    Phone
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="prefix-input">
  </div>
  <div>
    Fax
    <input type="tel" name="fax" class="prefix-input">
  </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kebse0z9/15/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I made that change and it doesn't remove the readonly either.

Comment: @user3052443 I would suggest checking your console, and setting up a JSFiddle so we can see the problem.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle but the initial blocking is not working. The same code works here so I must be missing something in the jsfiddle. Here is the link:https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/kebse0z9/13/

Comment: @user3052443 in the JSFiddle JavaScript window, you need to select the jQuery framework.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that part. Now the code is working as I originally explained. If you select Greece, you will see it displays a prefix that can't be edited, which is correct. Then select Please Select and try to type something in the box - doesn't allow it.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/kebse0z9/14/ But I can delete the +30 on my test (Chrome for Android).

Comment: I will say: if it is imperative that the country code is accurate, do not rely on a user input field. You should validate server-side, because users can easily adjust the +30 to something else. A better solution might be displaying the country code in a read-only input, next to this input.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE, FF or Chrome for me, though these are all on desktops if that matters. To be clear as to how it works, switch the dropdown to Greece, then switch it to Please Select. Then click in the input box and try to type something. You should be able to but can't, at least I can't.

Comment: Yes, but before we get to that, should I be able to delete the +30? Also, is the desired effect to make the entire input read-only? If so, why? If the prefix should be read-only, it should be kept separate.

Comment: No, you should not be able to delete the +30 once Greece is selected. You should be able to type in the rest of the phone number. That part is working. Which you switch away from Greece you should be able to type in the input box. That is not working. But it only fails after switching to Greece and back so the readonly change is not being removed.

Comment: OK, so on Chrome for Android, I can delete the +30. But on Firefox for Windows, I cannot. Readonly is false by default, and doesn't appear to be set to true anywhere in your fiddle.

Comment: rybo111: I missed the code you posted since the comments came after. I see that your example works but it is vastly different from my code and I don't have the experience to convert it. Thanks for the post. I will keep trying.

Comment: It would be a case of adding the classes to your existing select and inputs, and adding the `data-prefix` to each option. The jQuery code is reusable.